# Правильное преобразование SVG to PNG средствами php

Tags: php

Стоит Imagick
есть картинка в SVG у норгов https://www.yr.no/en/content/67.568007,33.391146/meteogram.svg
Задача налету переделать в png
пробую

```
$svg = file_get_contents($url);

$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg);

$im->setImageFormat("png24");

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $im;

$imagic->clear();
$imagic->destroy();
```

Выводи на экран черно белое и полупустое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите как преобразовать ее нормально?

Comment: Да всё ок с Вашим кодом. PHP 8, получил изображение в точности как SVG. У Вас какая версия?

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar php 7.4.3, imagick  3.4.4, ImageMagick supported formats: ... svg ... , блин

Comment: я бы попробовал чуть потанцевать с бубном. к примеру, убрать <?xml из readImageBlob(). (классика жанра, когда работает то так, то иначе). может вывод сделать, как // Display the image
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob(); ?

Comment: убрать <?xml  - я попробовал в первую очередь, без него была ошибка "Uncaught ImagickException: no decode delegate for this image format  @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361"

Comment: ну и $imagick->getImageBlob();  тоже ничего не дает, все тоже - обрезанное черно бело  изображение в первом сообщении :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло только  shell_exec('Inkscape file.svg file.png')

надо чтобы в системе была установлена приблуда Inkscape , которая заменяет exec(convert file.svg file.png)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]